# Stream audio from browser and pass all chunks to backend flask and do speech recognition using TF model and pass the result in frontend in realtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, pyaudio, speech

app.py

```html
from flask import Flask, Response,render_template
import pyaudio

app = Flask(__name__)


FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

 
audio1 = pyaudio.PyAudio()
 


def genHeader(sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels):
    datasize = 2000*10**6
    o = bytes("RIFF",'ascii')                                               # (4byte) Marks file as RIFF
    o += (datasize + 36).to_bytes(4,'little')                               # (4byte) File size in bytes excluding this and RIFF marker
    o += bytes("WAVE",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) File type
    o += bytes("fmt ",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Format Chunk Marker
    o += (16).to_bytes(4,'little')                                          # (4byte) Length of above format data
    o += (1).to_bytes(2,'little')                                           # (2byte) Format type (1 - PCM)
    o += (channels).to_bytes(2,'little')                                    # (2byte)
    o += (sampleRate).to_bytes(4,'little')                                  # (4byte)
    o += (sampleRate * channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(4,'little')  # (4byte)
    o += (channels * bitsPerSample // 8).to_bytes(2,'little')               # (2byte)
    o += (bitsPerSample).to_bytes(2,'little')                               # (2byte)
    o += bytes("data",'ascii')                                              # (4byte) Data Chunk Marker
    o += (datasize).to_bytes(4,'little')                                    # (4byte) Data size in bytes
    return o

@app.route('/audio')
def audio():
    # start Recording
    def sound():

        CHUNK = 1024
        sampleRate = 44100
        bitsPerSample = 16
        channels = 2
        wav_header = genHeader(sampleRate, bitsPerSample, channels)

        stream = audio1.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True,input_device_index=1,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
        print("recording...")
        #frames = []
        first_run = True
        while True:
           if first_run:
               data = wav_header + stream.read(CHUNK)
               first_run = False
           else:
               data = stream.read(CHUNK)
           yield(data)

    return Response(sound())

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')

      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True,port=5000)
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{ url_for('audio') }}" type="audio/x-wav;codec=pcm">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Using flask in backend I want to do the speech recognition using tensorflow model and for that i just want to modify this code so that it can do the speech recognition and pass that transcription in browser as realtime.
I am struggling on this issue since 3 days but not getting any desired result so it would be great if you can help me to add the feature.

Also there are few parameters for the audio file to get the desired output as channel should be mono, sample rate should be 16000 , file format should be .wav

Regards,
Mahendra Bagul